# Unable to change system string resource

Tags: java, android, xposed-framework

I am making a Xposed Module that would allow users to modify the message displayed on the lock screen when Wrong pattern, pin or password is entered.

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Replacing-resources).

After digging into the android source code on GitHub, I found out the method that displays the message on the lock screen, that was `onPatternChecked()` in the class `com.android.keyguard.KeyguardPatternView.java`. The method uses the `kg_wrong_pattern` string resource which has the value **Wrong Pattern** when wrong pattern is drawn.

This is how my class looks like:-

```
package com.batrashubham.customlockscreenerrormessage;

import android.content.res.XResources;

import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookInitPackageResources;
import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookZygoteInit;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_InitPackageResources;

/**
 * Created by shubham on 19/7/16.
 */
public class CustomErrorMessage implements IXposedHookInitPackageResources,IXposedHookZygoteInit {

    @Override
    public void initZygote(StartupParam startupParam) throws Throwable {
        XResources.setSystemWideReplacement("android","bool","config_unplugTurnsOnScreen",false);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInitPackageResources(XC_InitPackageResources.InitPackageResourcesParam resparam) throws Throwable {
        if(!resparam.packageName.equals("com.android.keyguard")){
            return;
        }
        XposedBridge.log("I just got into your lock screen");
        resparam.res.setReplacement("com.android.keyguard", "string", "kg_wrong_pattern", "Nice try.!!");
    }


}
```

The module is showing up in the Xposed Installer app and is successful activated, but still the original message is showing up on the lock screen when I draw a wrong pattern.

I am currently testing it on Android 6.0.1 (CyanogenMod 13).

What am I doing wrong?